# unable to create kafka stream from an avro topic

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm trying to create a stream from a kafka topic, the value format and key format for the topic are both avro, here's example of running ksql print on this topic :

```
Key format: AVRO
Value format: AVRO
rowtime: 2020/05/15 04:49:30.979 Z,
key:{
   "_id":{
      "_data":"825EBE1F57000000022B022C0100296E5A1004514E195BA8044B299EF9653C8B8A16D346645F696400645EBE1F572597108CA0F285D70004"

}
},
value:{
   "_id":{
      "_data":"825EBE1F57000000022B022C0100296E5A1004514E195BA8044B299EF9653C8B8A16D346645F696400645EBE1F572597108CA0F285D70004"

},
   "operationType":"insert",
   "clusterTime":{
      "$timestamp":{
         "t":1589518167,
         "i":2

}

},
   "fullDocument":{
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"5ebe1f572597108ca0f285d7"

},
      "ok":2.0

},
   "ns":{
      "db":"dev",
      "coll":"users"

},
   "documentKey":{
      "_id":{
         "$oid":"5ebe1f572597108ca0f285d7"

}

}
}
```

i'm executing the following command :

```
create stream s with(kafka_topic='dev.users', value_format='avro');
```

and i'm having the following error when i do so :

```
 Unable to verify if the schema for topic dev.users is compatible with KSQL.
Reason: KSQL stream/table schema must be structured

Please see https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/ to see if this particular reason is already known.
If not, please log a new issue, including the this full error message.
Schema:"string"
```

Comment: The error message is saying that when ksql retrieved the schema from the schema registry the schema was for a simple `string` type, not an Avro record. 

Both PRINT and CREATE STREAM are using the same deserializer code, so I'm unsure how you can end up with a different schema.  Can you share the PRINT command you issued to get this output and the version of ksqlDB you're running?

A secondary issue is that ksqlDB doesn't yet support Avro keys, though that won't stop you accessing the data in the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked into this more - they don't use the same deserializer.

The PRINT deserializer extracts the id of the schema used to serialize the data from the start of the data.

The CREATE STREAM will contact the Schema Registry *before* processing any data (after all the topic may be empty!), and ask it for the schema for subject '-value`or`dev.users-value` in your case.

So what it looks like is that the data in Kafka is prefixed with a schema id for one schema, and the schema registered under the `dev.users-value` subject is another schema.

Schema Registry supports different 'Subject Naming Strategies'.  KsqlDB only works with the default 'TopicNameStrategy'.  If could be that some other strategy is configured for this data. See https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#sr-schemas-subject-name-strategy for more info.